# C Unix - fork(), execl() and pipe in a loop

Tags: c, unix, exec, fork, pipe

I want to preface this with the fact that I have no formal education in the use of `pipes`, so this is my first venture.  Not to mention that I couldn't find any similar questions to my situation.

Note: This IS part of a larger project for a school assignment, so I am NOT asking for anyone to do this for me.  I would just like some direction/helpful code segments.  (I have tried to make this as generic as possible to avoid "cheater" remarks.)

I am trying to run a `for-loop` over `int k` elements in which a parent process spawns off `k` children with `fork()` and `execl()`, and then use a `pipe()` to send the output back to the parent.  Here is some generic code that I am trying to use and the error/problem in which I encounter:

Note: `helloworld`= an executable compiled with `GCC` that produces `printf("hello world\n");`

```
int k = 10; //The number of children to make
int fd[2]; //Used for each pipe
int readFromMe[k]; //Holds the file IDs of each pipe fd[0]
int writeToMe[k]; //Holds the file IDs of each pipe fd[1]
int processID[k]; //Holds the list of child process IDs

//Create children
int i;
for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    if(pipe(fd) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error - Pipe error.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Store the pipe ID
    readFromMe[i] = fd[0];
    writeToMe[i] = fd[1];

    if((processID[i] = fork()) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failure");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //If it is a child, change the STDOUT to the pipe-write file descriptor, and exec
    if(processID[i] == 0)
    {
        dup2 (writeToMe[i], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(readFromMe[i]);

        execl("./helloworld", (char *)0);
    }

    //If it is the parent, just close the unnecessary pipe-write descriptor and continue itterating
    else
    {
        close(writeToMe[i]);
    }
}

//Buffer for output
char output[100000];

//Read from each pipe and print out the result  
for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    int r = read(readFromMe[i], &output, (sizeof(char) * 100000));

    if(r > 0)
    {
        printf("result = %s\n", output);
    }

    close(readFromMe[i]);
}
```

I get no output from my program at all, so I am trying to figure out why this issue is occurring.

Comment: Check if the exec succeeds, and check if read returns 0 or -1, and if -1 check errno.

Comment: The execl is definitely causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably unrelated, but you call `execl` wrong. The extra arguments after the program is what will the the `argv` array to the other programs `main` function. And as you know it always have one entry, the program name. So you need to call it like this:

```
execl("./helloworld", "helloworld", NULL);
```

More related to your problem, you should also check for errors, it might actually fail.

Comment: It mentioned to cast the "NULL" sentinel to (char *) in other questions and that didn't seem to cause the issue.  I updated the missing parameter too.  Thanks :)

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma Do not change the question to reflect the solution. It is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the value of 'r' in your printout function.  I suspect the read is returning an error (perhaps EPIPE) that you're not seeing.  Also, you example code is trying to printf 'c', not output like it looks like you meant.

Comment: That was a copy/paste typo with "c" instead of "output".  I didnt want my homework posted online verbatim :P  But after checking "r", it turns out that it was merely an issue with execl.